# How does users.watch (in gmail google API) listen to the emails that are being sent?

Tags: gmail-api

I'm attempting to set up a push notification channel in the Gmail API to listen for emails sent from the Gmail web application. I have included the SENT label ID in the labelIds parameter of the users.watch request. However, I'm experiencing an issue where I am not receiving notifications for emails that I send from the Gmail web application, but I am receiving notifications for replies that I send to those emails. What could be causing this issue and how can I resolve it?

I tried the above scenario with the below code snippet.

```
const watchResponse = (
        await gmail.users.watch({
            userId: 'me',
            requestBody: { topicName, labelIds: ['INBOX', 'SENT', 'UNREAD'] },
        })
    ).data;
    userData.currentHistoryId = watchResponse.historyId;
    userData.watchExpTime = new Date(Number(watchResponse.expiration));
```